# How to recover the subsite from recycle bin in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, recycle-bin

How to recover the subsite from recycle bin in share point? I had deleted some sub sites currently. If I want to recover back those deleted sub sites, how to do it? Once i recover back will it effect anything since it is a sub site. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the below url:

```
http://sitecollection/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?View=2
```

How to go there:

1) Go to site settings > recycle bin

2) Click on "Second-stage recycle bin"

[image]

3) Or go to the above url directly. It opens the second stage recycle bin directly.

[image]

Make sure you have admin credentials.

You can restore it from there by clicking the checkbox of the subsite and pressing restore.

Once restored, it shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: Should note that items are deleted after 30 days (not sure if you can configure that in SPO).

Comment: welcome ! Please mark it as answer if it helped you. You will also get the "informed" badge :)